# add tr immediately after the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to let user add another input file immediately next down the button, so he can select and send     "x" number of files

[image]

Ive been using these answers while searching with no luck

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19200323/5586647
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19200278/5586647
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30098596/5586647
```

piece of my code where I want to insert new tr is

```
echo '<tr align=center ><td colspan="4"><input type="file" name="oc" id="oc"/></td><td><input type="button" value="add more" id="addme"/></td></tr>';
```

I would aprecciate a bit of help

**EDIT:**

While using the answers I got an issue that adds de tr (or I guess is a tr) but to a side of the original (using append)

[image]

and what I want is:

[image]

CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/9k4kmvmw/

Comment: Can you give us the html without all of the php tags?  Load your page on your development machine right click on the table and click inspect or inspect element.  Find the opening `<table>` tag and right click on it and you should be able to find an option to copy html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery `After();` [jquery.com/after/](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and a click event, and make sure the input name is an array[]

```
$('.addme').click(function(){
     $('.uploads').last('tr').after('<tr align=center ><td colspan="4"><input type="file" name="oc[]"/></td></tr>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j0jjzm7o/16/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can do this for you using `.append()` - [jquery.com/append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

An untested example...

Here is the HTML,

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="file" name="file[]" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">Add another</button>
```

and the javascript,

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  var string = '<tr><td><input type="file" name="file[]" /></td></tr>';
  $("#table").append(string);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some JavaScript(JQuery) to accomplish your task.

Live Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/Nxovdj

Place the following in a script tag before your closing body tag or load it from an external file after you load JQuery. If you are unsure how to load JavaScript through an external file you can download the example from this link and explore the index.html file.

[Example Download](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/share/zip/Nxovdj/)

```
//store the addme id
var addMe = "#addme";

//store the tr markup
var tr = '<tr align=center ><td colspan="4"><input type="file" name="oc" id="oc"/></td><td><input type="button" value="add more" id="addme" /></td></tr>';

//add the on click event
$(document).on("click",addme,function(){


  //select the table
  var table = $("#table"); 

  //append the tr
  table.append(tr);


});
```

Comment: Please post your complete table html ,including the opening and closing tags that way I can test in my live example to try and solve the issue.